# Binary Search Not Working sometimes for Even number Elements C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I have been trying to do binary search and I am just now learning about it. My program runs just fine with an odd number of elements, but when I have an even number of elements it will not consistently work. Here is my code:

Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 10;

void bubbleSort(int data[]){
    srand((time(0)));
    for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
        data[i] = rand() % 10;

    for(int x = 0; x < NUM_ELEMENTS-1; x++){
        for(int i = 0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS-1;i++){
            int temp = 0;
            if(data[i]>data[i+1]){
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[i+1];
                data[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int x = 0; x<NUM_ELEMENTS;x++)
        printf("%4d",data[x]);
}

bool binarySearch(int data[],int target){
    int start = 0;
    int end = NUM_ELEMENTS-1;
    while(start<=end){
        int mid = (start+end)/2;
        if(data[mid] == target){
            cout<<"\nTarget index is: "<<mid+1;
            return true;
        }
        else if(data[mid]<target)
            start = mid +1;
        else
            end = start - 1;
    }
    cout<<"\nTarget not found";
}

int main(){
    int data[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    bubbleSort(data);
    binarySearch(data,7);  
}
```

Comment: Try it with only 4 numbers, and debug your code step by step to see where your program goes wrong.

Comment: I'm surprised this works for odd or even numbers of elements. I'm pretty sure your `end = start - 1;` should really be `end = mid - 1;` to stand any real chance of working correctly. In the usual scheme of things (a half-open range) you really want `end = mid;` though. That is, you typically want your "end" iterator to point one past the end, not at the end. Eliminates a lot of corner cases and difficulty.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you so much, been messing around with this for hours now. Can't believe I did not pick up on that. I even wrote it all down on paper and I just saw I had that, but must have not noticed I had it wrong in my code.